# How to calculate expiry date using pdo prepare statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I need to calculate link expiry date with current date and created date to check if link is expired.
I am adding date to database as this format:

```
$expires = date("U") + 1800;
```

And trying to calculate like this:

```
 $currentDate = date("U");

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdResetSelector = :pwdResetSelector AND pwdResetExpires >= :pwdResetExpires");
$result->bindValue(':pwdResetSelector', $selector);
$result->bindValue(':pwdResetExpires ', $currentDate);
$result->execute();
```

But it doesn't calculate right and redirects me to error page instead of show form to fill details.

Comment: `prepared` should be `prepare`

Comment: sorry its `prepare` in original code and corrected in question and stil having same issue.

Comment: what's the datatype of `pwdResetExpires`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking for the query to return an expired value from the DB I think all you need to do is set your equality to less than or equal to.

If your expiration date is set in the DB as `date(U) + 1800` then obviously that is a future date.

So if today's date is greater than the `pwdResetExpires`date, there should be a reset because it has expired.

What your query is saying is `if the pwdResetExpires date is greater than today's date`.  This means that it is not expired because today's date still has not passed the `pwdResetExpires` date.

Where as if you say in your query `pwdResetExpires is less than today's date` then it has expired.

```
SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdResetSelector = :pwdResetSelector AND pwdResetExpires <= :pwdResetExpires
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to validate if currenDate is greater than `pwdResetExpires` looks like my query is correct, I am sending link and trying to confirm back in 3 minutes but it redirects me to error page, I am not sure should I check with less ?

Comment: If thats is the case then you are looking for dates that HAVE NOT expired?

Comment: yes, I am looking to check if current date is not passed `pwdResetExpires` in database.

Comment: Please post some additional code.  Where is the code that is examining the results of the query and redirecting to the error page?

Comment: Your answer made my mind clear, I made it work with greater date parameters, thanks for help, I  appreciate it.